# MongoDB Java driver: query where d>2,a="ABC",b="AA"

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

This is my sample data in mongodb,

```
{
    "a": "",
    "b": "",
    "c": "",
    "d": 0
},
{
    "a": "ABC",
    "b": "AA",
    "c": "12345678",
    "d": 1
}
```

This is my Java code for building the criteria and find query, but I am not getting data from MongoDb.

```
public Document buildCriteria(String a, String b, String c, String e,
                              String f, Double d) {

    Document criteria = new Document();

    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(a)) {
        criteria.append("country", a);
    }

    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(b)) {
        criteria.append("ccy", b);
    }

    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(c)) {
        criteria.append("type", c);
    }

    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(f)) {
        criteria.append("iCode", f);
    }


    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(e)) {
        criteria.append("aNumber", e);
    }

    if (null != d) {
        criteria.append("d", new Document("$gt", d));
    }

    return criteria;
}

Finderable<Document> findDocument = dbName.find(criteria).limit(10);
```

Can someone help me in getting the documents based on the following criteria, using Java code:

```
d>2, a="ABC", b="AA"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example, the in-line comments should help explain *how* to express `d>2 and a="ABC" and b="AA"` in terms which are understandable by the Mongo Java driver:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = ...;

// create a filter consisting of and'ed criteria
Bson filter = Filters.and(
        // d>2
        Filters.gt("d", 2),
        // a="ABC"
        Filters.eq("a", "ABC"),
        // b="AA"
        Filters.eq("b", "AA")
);

MongoCollection<Document> collection = mongoClient.getDatabase("...").getCollection("...");

FindIterable<Document> findDocument = collection.find(filter).limit(10);
```

Note: you don't explicitly mention what version of the Mongo Java driver you are using, the above code is valid for a 3.x version.